# Fetch the details from two different tables in single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called project and another table student. I want to fetch all the details about the project and all the details of the student in that project from single query. student table has project id as foreign key.There can be many students in a project.

Comment: As it's a one to many, a single SQL wouldn't be the best as it'll return redundant data, for example on each student rows it will also return all project details over and over again.

Comment: I agree, but any other better solution. I also dont want to fire two database queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select p.*,s.*(for all columns) from project p, Student s 
inner join p.id=s.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your response:). But I am looking for non redundant data

Answer (score 0):

Use a `INNER JOIN` and join both the table like below. That's basic set but you will be able to modify the `SELECT` column list per your need.

```
select s.* 
from student s
join project p on p.id = s.project_id;
```

Comment: This will be very inefficient, as it will return redundant project data for each student row.

Comment: this gives the information but as Jocelyn said it gives redundant information. Is there any other efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN for fetch data from both table using foreign key. So for this your query become like this

```
SELECT st.*,pr.* 
FROM student st
JOIN project pr ON pr.id = st.project_id;
```

I hope you will get solution.